# concatenation error when cancatenating 2 numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with nxm dimension
I need to slice out the second column but there is no direct way to do it, so I extracted out the first column and the columns from 3-m and then tried to concat them but its giving me error

let say dataset is my array with nxm dim

```
hstack((dataset[:,0], dataset[:,2:]))
```

this gives me error that they have unequal dim. When I look at their shape its gives me

```
dataset[:,0]   : n,
dataset[:,2:]  : n,m-2
```

What can be the issue here

Comment: Try `dataset[:, 0:1]` or `:1` or `[0]`, so this slice remains 2d.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer 
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html

Use column_stack for this